# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (4)

Tags: орфография

По моим сведениям, наречие "по-русски" образуется от прилагательного "русский", а наречие "по-немецки" образуется от прилагательного "немецкий". Правило образования указанных наречий и их аналогов имеет вид:

1) Zский -> по-Zски (например, рус**ский** -> **по-**рус**ски**),

2) Zцкий -> по-Zцки (например, неме**цкий** -> **по-**неме**цки**).

Предположим, я предложу, чтобы русские писали наречия "по-русски", "по-немецки" и т. п.  без небуквенного орфографического знака "-" (дефис).

**Вопрос:** Противоречит ли указанное предложение хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?

Answer (score 1):

Ничему не противоречит.

Правила это соглашения. Они могут меняться и меняются (хотя и медленно).

Comment: 1. Большое спасибо.

2. Если у Вас будет время, тогда взгляните на мои другие вопросы.

P.S. Мне нравятся лаконичные ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, будем путать существительные с предлогом и наречия.

Comment: Поясните Ваш ответ парой примеров "путаницы существительных с предлогом и наречий".

Answer (score 0):

Сществительных, прилагательных... короче, имен.
*По нашему городу, по имени*.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, как Вы намерены запутаться в предложениях "Он не назвал тов. Niemand по имени." и "Он позвал тов. Niemand понемецки.".

Comment: Так Вы хотите слитно писать?! Я думал, раздельно. ))
Что же, возможно, что лет через 200 так и будет. Надо, чтобы это ПО- успело стать полноценной приставкой.

Comment: Стало быть, в настоящее время "это ПО-" ещё не "успело стать полноценной приставкой".

P.S. "Возможно, что лет через 200" "это ПО-" "успеет стать полноценной приставкой".